# Call pusher server from frontend and also listen to the events from the same frontend

Tags: node.js, express, pusher

I have couple of Node.js endpoints where I integrated pusher. When I test these endpoints on postman, events get triggered successfully, and they show on my frontend.

Now due to the nature of the application I am building, I cannot call the endpoints on postman every time to trigger the events, I need to call those pusher endpoints from my frontend. I tried that and I get a successful response that the API to the pusher endpoint was successful, but I never got the data from the event from my frontend.

Below is my code:

```js
async function logMovies() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9990/trigger");
    console.log(response, "RESPONSE")
    const movies = await response.json();
    console.log(movies, "movies");
}

console.log("Hello Pusher")
let socketId = null;

async function returnSignature() {
    await logMovies()
    var pusher = new Pusher("<pusher_key>", {
        cluster: "mt1",
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe("dev");
    channel.bind("dev-event", (data) => {
        // Method to be dispatched on trigger.
        console.log(data, "My movies");
    });
}

returnSignature();
```

I'd appreciate any pointers that could help please